# jmeter extract regular expression not get correct result

Tags: regex, jmeter

This is my html

```
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="A9y6Ndf7Q2XP2Yz6zhaVChoIvpQGUrZRTvu9D_HnHnUcFBVInerxCjU4vpOXQYVhFwnzl-zAzkvtto7BLAVVr">
```

I want to extract value in jmeter Regular Expression Extractor.[image]

This is my regx window but when i post it i will not get expected token it is something like this `__RequestVerificationToken=%24%7Bauth_token%7D`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$1$` as a Template, it should resolve your issue.

Looking into your request I can see that you're sending `%24%7Bauth_token%7D` which being decoded looks like `${auth_token}` so you use case is not correct.

You need 2 requests:

1. GET request to get the page and extract RequestVerificationToken and store it to `auth_token` variable.
2. POST Request which will use `auth_token` variable.

See [Using Regular Expressions in JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-regular-expressions-jmeter) guide for more details.

By the way, you can use combination of [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to see if there are any matches. It should be more convenient w.r.t. groups and variables.

In general, it [isn't recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#answer-1732454) to use Regular Expressions to parse HTML. I would suggest to use [XPath Extractor](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) instead. Relevant XPath expression will look like:

```
//input[@name='__RequestVerificationToken']/@value
```

Few things to notice:

- If you page isn't XHTML compliant you'll need to check `Use Tidy` box in XPath Extractor
- JMeter 2.11 provides nice XPath Tester right in View Results Tree Listener

Comment: for every page "__RequestVerificationToken" will different so how i takecare that. i m using mvc4 & for each page there will be new token for example in login page token=123 & after login token=223

Answer (score 0):

We need to set the following Regular Expression Extractor values to extract the auth token values

```
Reference Name : Auth_Token
Regular Expression : <input\sname="__RequestVerificationToken"\stype="hidden"\svalue="(.+)">
Template : $1$
Match No : 1
Default values : NOT FOUND TOKENS
```